# PHP $_SESSION variable will not unset

Tags: php, session, variables, unset

sorry for a repetitive question, I've seen a few of these on this forum but none of the responses worked for me...

I am building a basic login using php sessions, which I'm new at...

login.php validates html login form and begins a session, setting variables: `$_SESSION['login']` and `$_SESSION['id]`,

then each page that requires a valid login uses `require 'session.php';` which checks the `$_SESSION['valid']` variable and redirects a user w/o proper login variable. The problem is when I logout neither session variable I've set will unset.

Right now my logout.php file uses about every method to destroy the variables that I've been able to find online and none will actually do it.

So whenever I log out, I can still access the 'private' pages.

Also note: I have tried it w/o a session name ex: `session_start();` that didn't work so now I'm using `session_start("user");`

Also note: I am NOT using cookies.

Here are the files I mentioned:

---

login.php

---

```
$email=$_POST['email-log']; $pass=$_POST['password-log'];

$i=-1;

do
{$i++; $path="users/".$i.".json";
$file=  file_get_contents($path);
$x=json_decode($file,true);
} while($x['email']!=$email);
$id=$i;
$truepass=$x['pass'];

$errors=0;
$hash=hash('sha256',$pass);
if($hash != $truepass){$errors=$errors+1;}

if($errors==0){
        session_start("user");
        $_SESSION['login']="valid";
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;

    header('Location: loginlanding.php');}

else{header('Location: front.php?error=y');}
```

---

session.php

---

```
session_start("user"); if($_SESSION['login'] !== "valid") {header('Location: front.php?needto=login');}
```

---

logout.php

---

```
unset($_SESSION); unset($_SESSION['login']); unset($_SESSION['id']); session_unset("user"); $_SESSION=array(); session_destroy("user"); header('Location: front.php?logged=out');
```

---

Any and all responses are welcome and I thank you in advance, also note, I am new to logins in general so any advice to beef up security is welcome also. I'm planning on making it more secure, but first I need to get this basic functionality up and running.

Comment: It seems obvious but just to be clear, when someone logs out, you force them to go to the logout.php page?

Comment: Is there a sane reason for anyone to be writing this kind of code themselves in 2012?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should never `unset($_SESSION)`.

The easiest way to clear the `$_SESSION` variable is `$_SESSION = Array();`

However, you can also iterate with `unset`:

```
foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);
```

Comment: ah ha! the problem was that on logout.php I never called session_start(); I didn't require session.php in that one so it never got called. Now my logout.php is as follows:

<?php  session_start(); session_unset(); session_destroy("user"); header('Location: front.php?logged=out');

-Works, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Why are you adding `session_destroy("user");`? It doesn't do anything. Just do `session_destroy();`

Answer (score 13):

It's amazing how many things you're attempting to do *after* you've unset the **only** reference you had to the session in the first place. Directly from the manual:

> **Caution**
>
> Do NOT unset the whole [*`$_SESSION`*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) with **`unset($_SESSION)`** as this will disable the registering of session variables through the [*`$_SESSION`*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

You're unsetting `$_SESSION` so your unsets to the other arrays of the super global `$_SESSION` aren't registering, leaving them still in the browsers temporary cookies. Use `session_unset()` instead if you're trying to remove **all** session variables. Otherwise, don't **unset** the session global, but unset each individual value of it you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

My working example (notice that you must put start on the call)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('location: ./');
?>
```