# accessing session array data, deleting or changing one of the variables within this array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my session array:

```
Array ( [username] => dog@dog.net [tmpPayment] => Array ( [mID] => 48 [item_1_amt] => 35.00 [description] => Student ) )
```

I created the ['tmpPayment'] array with the following code:

```
$tmpPayArr = array();
$tmpPayArr = array('mID'=>$mID,'item_1_amt'=>'35','description'=>'student');
$_SESSION['tmpPayment'] = $tmpPayArr;
```

I have looked for a simple answer to three questions: (1)how do I add a variable to the [tmpPayment] array (2)how do I change the value of [amount] variable within the [tmpPayment] array (3)how do I remove/delete the [tmpPayment] array altogether. (4)how do I assign the value of ['tmpPayment']['mID'] to a new variable $memberID. For (3) I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
unset($_SESSION['tmpPayment']);
```

I think my main problem is not understanding how to REFERENCE the array and its variables properly.

UPDATE:
I have successfully added and change my SESSION variable with the following:

```
$_SESSION['tmpPayment']['item_1_amt'] = $x_amount;
$_SESSION['tmpPayment']['description'] = $x_invoice_num;
```

Is this best practice?
Still need help with (3)...removing the session variable ['tmpPayment'] from the above session array.

Comment: QUESTION: why when I use the following code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers.  If they aren't working, be sure you're calling `session_start();` before you try to modify the $_SESSION array.

1. `$_SESSION['tmpPayment']['new_key_name'] = 'new value';`
2. `$_SESSION['tmpPayment']['item_1_amt'] = 12324;`
3. `unset($_SESSION['tmpPayment']);`

Comment: QUESTION: why when I use the following code and refresh my page: `<?php 
session_start();
include('debug-code.php');
require_once('configdb.php');
require('functions.php');
$loginCheck = loginCheck();
unset($_SESSION['tmpPayment']);
$totalDonation = 0;
$invoiceTotal = 0;` the $_SESSION['tmpPayment'] IS NOT REMOVED...but when I create a new file with the following code `<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['tmpPayment']);
?>` THE SESSION IS REMOVED.  My objective is to make sure that if a user leaves the page that their payment choices are reset.

Comment: @Leslie start commenting out code piece by piece until you figure out what's causing it to not work.  Special focus can be given to functions that start with "session_" if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

1: `$_SESSION["tmpPayment"]["newVariable"] = "value";`

2: `$_SESSION["tmpPayment"]["amount"] = "$1.78";`

3: To do this, you can set `["tmpPayment"]` to an empty array like so:
`$_SESSION["tmpPayment"] = array();`

or set it to null

`$_SESSION["tmpPayment"] = null;`

I borrowed a bit from this answer: [PHP $_SESSION variable will not unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291835/php-session-variable-will-not-unset)

and as that answer, and the other poster on this question mention, make sure to call `session_start();` before doing anything with the session variables.